# how to read text file from internet in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, text-files, readfile

I want to read a remote text file and show its content in a textview. I have written this  code, but it doesn't get any information from the text file and has "force stop" error. How can I find the reason of this problem or solve it? isn't there anything wrong in my code?

```
private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {
protected void doInBackground() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://host/f.txt");       
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        //get lines
        }
        in.close();
        lbl.setText(line);
    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
protected void onProgressUpdate() {
    //called when the background task makes any progress
}
protected void onPreExecute() {
     //called before doInBackground() is started
}
protected void onPostExecute() {
     //called after doInBackground() has finished 
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

and my onCreate code:

```
DownloadFile d=new DownloadFile();
d.doInBackground();
```

please solve my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things:

1) You cannot modify the UI thread from a background Thread. `doInBackground()` runs on a background Thread, you should update your UI on `onPostExecute()`.

2) You have two implementations of `doInBackground()`. The first one doesn't override the `doInBackground()` in AsyncTask. Move this code to the one that overrides AsyncTask

3) `doInBackground()` should return a String so you can use it to update the text on your TextView in onPostExecute. AsyncTask should look like this `AsyncTask<String,Void,String>`

4) When you create the `DonwloadFile()` instance you should invoke its execute(), otherwise the background Thread will not start and `doInBackground()` will not get called.

5) Your while loop is only checking if there is still data on the InputStream, but it is not storing it anywhere. Use a `StringBuilder` to append incoming information like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492076/android-reading-from-an-input-stream-efficiently).

Answer (score 0):

It is easier for people to help you if you post the exception stack trace from Logcat.

If you are using Eclipse and don't know what I am talking about, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188115/what-is-logcat-in-eclipse)