# error in http post request in android

Tags: android, http, post

Here is my code. I am getting error in this , please help me complete it.
 I am trying to post a http request to my server with some data in my android app.

```
        package com.example.firstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.firstapp.ShakeDetector.OnShakeListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private CrystalBall mCrystalBall = new CrystalBall();
    private ApiCall mApiCall = new ApiCall();
    private TextView mAnswerLabel;
    private Button mGetAnswerButton;
    private ImageView mCrystalBallImage;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private ShakeDetector mShakeDetector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Assign the Views from the layout file
        mAnswerLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        mGetAnswerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mCrystalBallImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        mGetAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                handleNewAnswer();
                mApiCall.postData();
            }
        });

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mShakeDetector = new ShakeDetector(new OnShakeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onShake() {
                handleNewAnswer();
            }
        });
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Yes this is toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Log.d("Main Activity", "from oncreate() function");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mShakeDetector, mAccelerometer, 
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mShakeDetector);
    }

    private void animateCrystalBAll() {
        mCrystalBallImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball_animation);
        AnimationDrawable ballAnimtion = (AnimationDrawable) mCrystalBallImage.getDrawable();
        if(ballAnimtion.isRunning()) {
            ballAnimtion.stop();
        }
        ballAnimtion.start();
    }

    private void animateAnswer() {
        AlphaAnimation fadeInAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
        fadeInAnimation.setDuration(1500);
        fadeInAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        mAnswerLabel.setAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
    }

    private void playSound() {
        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.crystal_ball);
        player.start();
        player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();
            }
        });
    }



}
```

Here is ApiCall.java. In this file I am using http post request

```
package com.example.firstapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class ApiCall extends AsyncTask {
    public void postData() {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();    
          HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://dailydeal.in/android/Api.php");      
                try {        

                     List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();        
                     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gmail","mail@gmail.com"));

                     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); 
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);             
                 } 
                catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
                {       
                     e.printStackTrace(); 
                 } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {         
                     e.printStackTrace();
                  }
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    } 
}
```

Comment: What "error in this" ?

Comment: I did not know. I am new in android. when I run this code I am getting  unfortunately, your application is stopped

Comment: I think the error in this line  HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

Comment: check and post the logcat, you can do it like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280051/how-to-enable-logcat-console-in-eclipse-for-android)

Comment: Note that, "postData" method should run in a separate thread, so, you should run it inside new Thread / AsyncTask

Comment: what to check in logcat. I can see some error lines. first line is saying fatal exception main

Comment: you don't know how to read the logcat?

Comment: what is the second line..?!

Comment: @EslamYousefMohammed I did not get you, please explain.

Comment: @mihail yes I am new in android I dont know how to read logcat

Comment: @Sunilomrey you are making a good suspense thriller out of this. Just paste the all lines of the logcat after the "first line is saying fatal exception main"...those are the lines that tell you what is wrong and where. Also go through [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188115/what-is-logcat-in-eclipse)  and the one i mentioned above

Comment: Running any network operation MUST be in a separate thread not in the Main thread, because network operations may block the UI for the user which is not allowed in APIs > 11, So, you need to run any network operation Like "postData" in a separate Thread/ AsyncTask.

Comment: @user2450263 how to copy all the lines, is there a sorter way.

Comment: select them, normal copy-paste the selection , that is the shortest way if you meant that

Comment: @EslamYousefMohammed what do you mean by separate thread. means it should not be in main activity. should I create a new class

Comment: @user2450263 I am using eclipse. I am unable to select the lines

Comment: yes, it must run inside "Thread / AsyncTask" class..check this
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_network_connection.htm

Comment: @EslamYousefMohammed what do you mean by Thread / AsyncTask class. I have putted postData() in a new class name ApiCall. is that ok?

Comment: Check the URL in my last comment, it's explaining the answer with example.

Comment: @EslamYousefMohammed done but still getting the same error

Comment: What is the second line in your logcat..?!

Comment: second line 04-28 06:13:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(2949): Process: com.example.firstapp, PID: 2949

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51590/discussion-between-eslam-yousef-mohammed-and-sunil-omrey)

Answer (score 1):

- Please make sure that you have requested INTERNET permission on manifest
- postData() function must be called on separate thread because you can't run request network on main thread. You can user Asynctask or service

  private class PostDataAsynTask extends AsyncTask {

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onPreExecute();

  }


  @Override
  protected ApiModel doInBackground(String... params) {

      // Call your post data funciton here
      return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(ApiModel result) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onPostExecute(result);

      // Do your stuff after post data here
  }
  ```

  }

Then on you MainActivity

```
new PostDataAsynTask().excute("");
```

Comment: I have giver permission for internet. I have postData() in a class name ApiCall other than MainActivity.

Comment: Can you post logcat ?

Comment: 04-28 06:13:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(2949): Process: com.example.firstapp, PID: 2949  04-28 06:13:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(2949): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException  04-28 06:13:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(2949):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)

Comment: ==> postData() function must be called on separate thread because you can't run request network on main thread. You can user Asynctask or service

I mean you should create new separate thread to call postData() functions.

Please see my new answer

Comment: I have postData in new class name ApiCall.java Please see my updated question. where is your new answer

Comment: Please put code on postData in onDoInbackground() functions.
And call : APICall.excute(); to excute your post data code.

I updated my answer, not new answer, sorry

Comment: should I create a new function called onDoInbackground()

Comment: No, just override it.
Please see this tutorial (6.5 Asynctask)
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html
And google doc for more detail about Asynctask
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();    
  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(YOUR URL);      
        try {        

             List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();        
             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gmail","mail@gmail.com"));

             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); 
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);             
         } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
        {       
             e.printStackTrace(); 
         } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {         
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

make sure that your database contains field "gmail"

php

```
   <?php

    mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");

    mysql_select_db("db_name"); 


    $a1= (isset($_POST['gmail'])) ? $_POST['gmail'] : '';

    $ins="insert into Table_name(gmail)values('$a1')";

    mysql_query($ins);
     mysql_close();
   ?>
```

Comment: 04-28 06:13:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(2949): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 06:13:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(2949): Process: com.example.firstapp, PID: 2949
04-28 06:13:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(2949): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-28 06:13:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(2949):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
04-28 06:13:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(2949):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)

Comment: 04-28 06:13:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(2949):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
04-: E/AndroidRuntime(2949):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
04-2 E/AndroidRuntime(2949):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
04-28 06:13:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(2949):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
: E/AndroidRuntime(2949):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)

Comment: 04-28 06:13:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(2949):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
04-28 06:13:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(2949):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)

Comment: 04-28 06:13:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(2949):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-28 06:13:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(2949):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-28 06:13:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(2949):  at com.example.firstapp.ApiCall.postData(ApiCall.java:30)

Comment: add these lines in your post code    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy2 = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

                  StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy2);

Comment: 04-28 06:13:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(2949):  at com.example.firstapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:58)
04-28 06:13:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(2949):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
04-28 06:13:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(2949):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
04-28 06:13:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(2949):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-28 06:13:57.835: E/AndroidRuntime(2949):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

Comment: what do you mean by strictmode etc

Comment: please post your full code.I didn't understand your prblm yet