# How to check if sensor if lower then 1 - Android

Tags: java, android

I am wondering how can I check if a sensor value is less than 1?

For example:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.values[1] < 1) { // How to check if sensor is lower then 1.00
        // Do something
    }
}
```

This currently crashing my app.

Comment: Show the logcat output. Check if your `event` variable is null and if size of values is greater than 1.

Comment: use 
if( event.values.length>1 && event.values[1] < 1 ) { // check if sensor is lower then 1.00
            // Do something
  }

Comment: Sorry guys. I get error when I had Display.setText(x);  this in IF. Just added Display.setText("" + x); and works. Sorry again!

Comment: Please read [ask] and improve your question accordingly. Most people are patient with beginner questions but as is, it may get some downvotes for (missing) quality.

Comment: @Mjafko *"This currently gives me a crash"* — You should always add the stacktrace to the question. What's the error message? What does the [Logcat](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7188115/507738) say?